# Ant and Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: ant, bitbucket-pipelines

I am new to bit bucket pipeline . My Project is in Java with Ant build  and i want an sample bitbucket-pipeline.yml file with ant build .Any insight will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can find templates here in the validator: https://bitbucket-pipelines.atlassian.io/validator.

If you select the "change the template" option in the configure sidebar in the left side it can generate boilerplate for each language/platform.

I also used this as a solid template to start building my node pipeline.